# How to avoid nested for loops in matlab?

Tags: matlab, vectorization, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

I am constructing an adjacency list based on intensity difference of the pixels in an image. 
The code snippet in Matlab is as follows:

```
m=1;
len = size(cur_label, 1);
for j=1:len
    for k=1:len
        if(k~=j)    % avoiding diagonal elements
            intensity_diff = abs(indx_intensity(j)-indx_intensity(k));     %intensity defference of two pixels.

            if intensity_diff<=10     % difference thresholded by 10
                adj_list(m, 1) = j;   % storing the vertices of the edge
                adj_list(m, 2) = k;
                m = m+1;
            end
        end
    end
end
y = sparse(adj_list(:,1),adj_list(:,2),1);       % creating a sparse matrix from the adjacency list
```

How can I avoid these nasty nested for loops? If the image size is big, then its working just as disaster. If anyone have any solution, it would be a great help for me.
Regards
Ratna

Comment: hi, and welcome,.... first standart anwser for this kind of problem would be [vectorisation](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) ( a few [Tricks](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/programs/Matlab/tricks.html) )

Comment: Can you precise what `cur_label` and `indx_intensity` are ? Is it always a square image of size `len` by `len` ?

Comment: cur_label is a vector (suppose 120x1, means there is 120 pixels or vertices for the adjacency matrix) one cluster from a image. And indx_intensity is the gray values of those pixels (120 gray values). As there is 120 vertices, the adjacency matrix will be of size 120x120.

Comment: @RatnaSaha Would be nice if you could edit the question with those details and also add the sizes of the inputs involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the input `indx_intensity` as a `1D` array here. With that assumption, here's a vectorized approach with [`broadcasting/bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
%// Threshold parameter
thresh = 10;

%// Get elementwise differentiation between elements in indx_intensity
diffs = abs(bsxfun(@minus,indx_intensity(:),indx_intensity(:).')) %//'

%// Threshold the differentiations against the threshold, thus giving us a 
%// 2D square matrix. Then, set the diagonal elements to zero to avoid them.
mask = diffs <= thresh;
mask(1:len+1:end) = 0;

%// Get the indices of the TRUE elements in the valid mask as final output.
[R,C] = find(mask);
adj_list_out = [C R];
```

Comment: How do you avoid the diagonal elements `if(k~=j)`?

Comment: @kkuilla Ah it's okay. `k~=j` meant we are to skip diagonal elements in that 2D mask array that spans across `i's` and `j's`. Here `i` and `j` both represent the length of `indx_intensity`. This setting of diagonal elements is being done with `mask(1:len+1:end) = 0`. Hope this made sense :)

Comment: @Divakar - Thanks for your answer. I was trying as below in vectorized form: ` intens = indx_intensity(:,1);
    [r, c] = size(intens);
    b = repmat(intens, c, r);
    adj = (abs(bsxfun(@minus, b, intens'))<=10);
    adj =adj- diag(diag(adj));
    y = sparse(adj);`   I was creating adjacency matrix. But your one I found time efficient. Thanks again.