# How to avoid nested for loops in this particular case?

Tags: matlab, performance, nested-loops

I have written a BFS (Breadth First Search) path planning algorithm. It works perfectly fine with the small grids (e.g. 15 by 15) but it is a disaster when it comes to larger grids (e.g. 150 by 250). Using the *tic* and *toc* commands, I found where it takes the most time (the least efficient bit) and the issue is to do with a nested for loop. I know use of nested for loops is considered bad and I need help with replacing it with something else (by avoiding the use of loops if possible).

```
for j=1:length(F)
    for k = 1:length(Closed)
        if(F(j) == Closed(k))
            F(j) = 0;
        end
    end
end

Closed = [Closed current];
```

The purpose of this section of the code is to replace the element of *F* that is the parent node (where we came from). So that any repetition can be ignored.

- *F* is a 1 by *n* vector storing neighbor nodes that can be traveled from the current node.

Note: I am using 8-connected space, hence *n* is always less than 8.

- *Closed* is initiated as an empty vector and it is used to store the list of visited nodes (by concatenating horizontally).
- *current* is a number between 1 and 37901, representing the current node.

I know there is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417710/how-to-avoid-nested-for-loops-in-matlab) about nested loops but my question is different. Thanks for you help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your "update". Why only compare against the last 10 elements in `Closed`? That is not reflected in your original code. My answer doesn't take that into account, though I'm sure you can modify it to do so if you need it. Note that you can do `Closed([end-9:end])` to get the last 10 elements.

Comment: @CrisLuengo For a second I thought the parent node can only be in the last n elements of Closed. Since n is always less than 8 I checked the last 10 elements of Closed instead of checking the entire vector. You can ignore it. It did't work as I expected. I am implementing your answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this bit of code is slow is not that you have nested loops, but that you implemented a O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm.

You should use a logical array to indicate nodes that are "closed". This will make the lookup much more efficient.

Consider you have `N = 37901` nodes. Initialize your `Closed` array thus:

```
Closed = false(1,N);
```

Now to check if node `F(j)` is closed, you can simply do `Closed(F(j))`, which will be `true` if it's closed.

Now your loop can be replaced with

```
F(Closed(F)) = [];
Closed(current) = true;
```

because `Closed(F)` is an array of the same size as `F` that is true for the closed nodes. You can use this array to index into `F`, and remove all the closed nodes. I'm deleting those nodes, rather than assigning 0 to them, so that `F` can always be used to index into `Closed`. If we write 0 there, it's no longer a logical array. If you need to not change the shape of `F`, you'd have to do some additional tests before indexing.

Note that `Closed = [Closed current]` is also a lot slower than `Closed(current) = true`, because it creates a new array that the old `Closed` array is copied into.

---

Note that you can remove the nested loop in your code, as below, but it will not necessarily be any faster, as the algorithm is still O(n<sup>2</sup>) (you're comparing each of the elements in `F` to each of the elements of `Closed`).

```
for j=1:length(F)
   if any(F(j) == Closed)
      F(j) = 0;
   end
end
```

Comment: F(Closed(F)) = 0; gives me an error. Are you sure about this?

Comment: Ah, my bad. We're writing 0 to the vector `F`, which you can then no longer use to indexing. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: If this is what you are suggesting,                                                      `for j=1:length(F)
            if(Closed(F(j))==true)
                F(Closed(F)) = [];
            end
        end`                                                                                             This will not work unless you do `F(Closed(F(j))) = [];` which doesn't really improve the performance.

Comment: @canberk_gurel: no, I'm not suggesting that. I'm suggesting no loop at all. Your loops over `j` and `k` can be replaced with `F(Closed(F)) = [];`. If you need a more detailed answer, post more of your code.

Comment: "Now to check if node `F(j)` is closed, you can simply do `Closed(F(j))`, which will be `true` if it's closed." made me think you are suggesting the use of an if condition and since you used `F(j)` I assumed there should be a for loop (e.g. `for j=1:length(F)`)

Comment: Yes, `Closed(F(j))` checks to see if neighbor `j` is closed. `Closed(F)` checks all neighbors at once. It returns an array of the same length as `F`, with `true` and `false` values. You can use that array to index into `F`, selecting those elements that returned `true`.